# Importing SQLAlchemy DateTimeMixin raises ImportErrror

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am trying to import `sqlalchemy.databases.sqlite.DateTimeMixIn`. I get `ImportError: No module named sqlite`. SQLAlchemy 0.8.4 is installed. If I do `import sqlite` I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following instead:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.base import _DateTimeMixin
```

Package `sqlalchemy.databases` is there for compatibility with pre-0.6 only. See [`lib/sqlalchemy/databases/__init__.py`](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/src/2537773d1e8c43cf751b77b269786ee9fd23777b/lib/sqlalchemy/databases/__init__.py?at=master).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the python binary you are using wasn't compiled with the sqlite module.  If you are compiling from source, make sure you have the sqlite headers available.